# Execute perl script with arguments in R

Tags: r, perl

I have a perl script (SFDRv166.pl, available here http://bit.ly/1DGmUTL) that I run successfully from the command line using:

```
perl SFDRv166.pl -assoc input.txt -SFDR -out test
```

I now need to run this program as part of an R script, and have tried implementing it as follows:

```
arg1 <- shQuote("-assoc input.txt")
arg2 <- shQuote("-SFDR")
arg3 <- shQuote("-out test")

system("perl SFDRv166.pl arg1 arg2 arg3")
```

However, I get an `ERROR: cannot find !` message generated I believe because the arguments are not getting passed to the perl script (output says no input or output file specified, and no output is created).

I can see from reading the documentation for `system()` that arguments with spaces require special handling, which is why I have tried to use `shQuote()`. Not sure what else may be wrong with my approach?

Comment: Use `paste`: `system(paste("perl","SFDRv166.pl",arg1,arg2,arg3))`

Comment: Look at the source for `xls2sep` in the gdata package. It calls perl with arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
arg1 <- "-assoc input.txt"
arg2 <- "-SFDR"
arg3 <- "-out test"
cmd <- paste("perl", "SFDRv166.pl", arg1, arg2, arg3)
system(cmd)
```

Now you don't need `shQuate`.